# Timefold constraint to check even distribution

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, timefold

I am very new to Timefold, having taken over a moderately simple engine designed by someone else who is not unavailable for questions.

I have cleaned a lot, but the challenge I am left with now is trying to check that a series of task assignments are evenly spread between all possible employees.

```
class Employee {
var assignedTasks: MutableList<TaskAssignment>
fun getTaskCount(): Int{
        return assignedTasks.size
    }
}
```

what I want is a constraint that penalizes the solution by deviation from the minimum. 4 tasks per employee is not a penalty, but 1 task per employee with 1 employee getting 4 tasks is a penalty (and what I want is probably the square of the difference)

| Distribution | Penalty |
| --- | --- |
| 1,1,1 | 0 |
| 5,5,5 | 0 |
| 5,1,1 | 16 |
| 5,1,0 | 26 |

and so on. I want to penalize by the task count, but reduced by the overall minimum task count

What I have so far is

```
return constraintFactory.forEach(Employee::class.java)
            .filter { employee -> employee.getTaskCount() > 1 }
            .penalize(HardMediumSoftLongScore.ofSoft(1)) { employee: Employee ->
                pow(employee.getTaskCount(), 2)
            }
            .asConstraint("Load balance the tasks per employee.")
```

This assumes the baseline of 1, but what it means is my 5,5,5 scenario still generates a penalty of 16*3, even though from a balance perspective, they are perfectly balanced. I need a way to find the minimum value in my solution. I have been pouring over the Timefold docs, but so far I am only seeing ways to penalize entries based purely on their own merits. I feel there is some solution in the `groupBy` logic, but I need to dig into it further.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/issues/545